# Difference bettween transformTuple and For loop on query Result - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have an HQL as `select p,c from Person p,ContactCard c where c.fk_pid=p.id` I executed this query as HQL using this code:

```
List<Person> personsWithContactCard = new ArrayList<Person>();
List<object[]> quryResult =  new ArrayList<object[]>();
String qry = "select p,c from Person p,ContactCard c where c.fk_pid=p.id";              
quryResult = session.createQuery(qry).list();

for(object[] obj : quryResult ) 
{
 Person person = new Person();
 person = (Person)obj[0];
 person.setContactCard = (ContactCard )obj[1];
 personsWithContactCard.add(person);
 person=null;
}
```

By taking query result in list of object array and looping on query result I fill persons list.

But after reading about `ResultTransformer` Interface I come to know that with this interface I can transform queryResult in to desired list so I changed my code To :

```
String qry = "select p,c from Person p,ContactCard c where c.fk_pid=p.id";

personsWithContactCard = session.createQuery(qry).setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() {                
@Override
public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) 
{
 Person person = new Person();
 person = (Person)obj[0];
 person.setContactCard = (ContactCard )obj[1];
 return person ;
}

@Override
public List transformList(List collection) 
{
return collection;
}
}).list();
```

This code gives me persons list with for looping.

**So my question is :** What is the difference between transformTuple and For loop? 
Does the both are same in performance and processing sense? 
Which will be more good as per performance?

And what is the use of `transformList()`?

**Update :**

After understanding use of `ResultTransformer` as explained in answer given by @bellabax I did one small change in code as follows:

```
personsWithContactCard = session.createQuery(qry).setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() {                
    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) 
    {
     Person person = new Person();
     person = (Person)obj[0];
     person.setContactCard = (ContactCard )obj[1];
     return person ;
    }

    @Override
    public List transformList(List collection) 
    {
    return null;
    }
    }).list();
```

I changed `transformList()` method to return `null` if I execute this code I am getting null `personsWithContactCard` list. Why `transformList()` method is need to return `collection` when I am not using it? And when I supposed to use `transformList()` and `transformTuple()` means how I can decide which to use?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't differences in terms of result usually, but using a `ResultTransformer`:

1. is the standard Hibernate method to process tuple and future (break) changes about how HQL is processed and tuple returned will be masked by a ResultTransformer without code changes
2. give you the possibilities to decorate or delegate (for example)

so the choice is the `ResultTransformer`.

About `ResultTransformer.transformList()`:

> Here we have an opportunity to perform **transformation on the query
>   result as a whole**

instead in `transformTuple` you can manipulate only one row of returned set.

**EDIT:**
As quoted above the javadoc of `ResultTransformer.transformList()` is pretty clear: this function allow to modify the whole list to remove duplicate, apply type conversion and so on and the result of `ResultTransformer.transformList()` is forwarded to `Query.list()` method so, return `null` from `transformList` whill return `null` from `list()`.
This is how `Query` and `ResultTransformer` are tied.

Comment: That means `transformTuple` internally works as `For loop` only, its just a way that how HQL is processed and tuple returned will be masked. So I will not get as much performance benefit from `ResultTransformer`. Means suppose if I get thousands (80k) of records from HQL then use of `For loop` or `ResultTransformer` don't make big difference, Right?

Comment: According to your example, you are looping on list which is returned from hibernate query, in `transformTuple` case Hibernate will work tuple-by-tuple (per row) to cast your object then add it into list. So instead of cast after you can transfor result at the time of fetching only.

Comment: as @user1372488 wrote your example is similar to write a custom `ResultTransformer` and do for-loop in `transformList()`

Comment: Thank you @bellabax and user1372488, I have one more doubts which is updated in question please clear that also if possible.